# Validation rule to check if a NUMBER field is blank doesn't seem to work

Tags: validation-rule, number

I created a Validation rule like below :

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Rate_Type__c, 'Custom'), 
  ISBLANK(Script_ID__c)
)
```

Script_ID__c is of `Number(18,0)` data type

**Unit testing**

Scenario 1:
When I fill Rate Type = Custom AND Script_ID__c = NULL

Error message comes as expected!

Scenario 2:
When I fill Rate Type = Custom AND Script_ID__c = 3252352

Error message comes - There is supposed to be NO error prompts

Why is Scenario 2 not working? how to adjust my VR to make it work for both scenarios?

Comment: any chance you have a before save trigger or flow that is coercing `Script_Id__c` to null?  VRs run after before insert|save flows/triggers

Comment: @cropredy nope definitely not flow/ trigger. I found a solution and will answer my own question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to solve this that I found was to create a **Formula(Text)** field with the formula `TEXT(Script_ID__c)` called something like **ScriptIDWorkaroundFormula__c**

Then in the Validation Rule, update it with the workaround **Formula(Text)** field and it works perfectly. So like

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Rate_Type__c, 'Custom'), 
  ISBLANK(ScriptIDWorkaroundFormula__c)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit delayed, but it seems that there is a way to solve this issue with no hack/workaround field needed using formula below:

```
ISNUMBER(TEXT(YourNumberField__c))
```

Tested in using Numbers with/without decimal point, and all looks good so far.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use ISNULL for number data type instead of ISBLANCK.

> To check the null condition for text data type we should use `ISBLANCK`
>
> To check the null condition for number data type we should use `ISNULL`

Your validation rule like below.

```
 AND(
  ISPICKVAL(Rate_Type, 'Custom'), 
  ISNULL(Script_ID__c)
)
```

Comment: nope wrong it doesn't work. Also we should always use ISBLANK instead of ISNULL in new formulas. ISBLANK has the same functionality as ISNULL but also supports text fields. Salesforce will continue to support ISNULL

Comment: Choose Treat blank fields as blanks for your formula when referencing a number, percent, or currency field in an ISNULL. Refer the https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isnull.htm&type=5

Comment: and your validation rule fire, when Rate_Type = 'custom' & Script_ID__c field is empty. when both fields you have values then validation rule will not fire.

Comment: @compski, The same validation rule which i mentioned in the answer was working for me.

Comment: haha so you downvoted my question because it works for you - yet it doesn't work for me or anyone

Comment: @compski, I have not down voted your question. Some one had done it.  As per your answer you have not done directly with ISBLANK function on Number field, finally you made it to text using formula.